Python re, extract path from text
I receive a text like:
`D:\Programming\sit\bin\MyLab.json`

It may contain different kind of quotes or may not contain them. Quotes if present are placed strictly at the beggining and at the end of the text, wrapping the path. But the text definately contains absolute windows path of a file. But this file may also be absent. I am struggling to write algorythm extracting the path.
I have tried regex like:
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]:\\((?:[a-zA-Z0-9() ]*\\)*).*', a)

but I receive:
['Programming\\sit\\bin\\']

But I expect to get string with path like:
D:\Programming\sit\bin\MyLab.json


Omit the capture group from the regex, that is being returned by re.findall.

The pathlib is probably what you are actually trying to achieve. Regex seems overkill here.

This is just an idea, but if you're sure that the path will always be an absolute Windows path, and that the quotes (if present) will always match, then maybe it isn't necessary to use Regex? Instead just check if the first character is an alphabet (the volume letter), and strip the first and last character if it isn't? Something like:
import string


def normalize_windows_path(a: str) -> str:
    if a[0] in string.ascii_letters:
        return a
    else:
        return a[1:-1]


You placed the capturing group at a wrong place. Regex ([a-zA-Z]:\\(?:[\w ]*\\)*[\w \.]*) works on your example.
However, extracting path using this method is a bad idea, since the valid character set for filenames is large. You may consider parsing your file in a different way.

ahhh yes, I dont feel good with regex...

I would go about this differently and instead try to return a pathlib instance as suggested in a comment
EDIT: this is really a more careful version of the now accepted answer, which may be more or less desirable depending on your use case
from pathlib import WindowsPath, PureWindowsPath
from string import ascii_letters

def regularize_windows_path(path_str):
    """ returns a pure or WindowsPath and whether the file exists
        in the case of a non-windows platform, exists is always None
    """
    if len(path_str) < 4 or not re.match(r"^.?[a-zA-Z]:", path_str):
        raise ValueError(r"expected an absolute string of a form like x:\path")
    # slice unmatched quotes
    if path_str[0] not in ascii_letters:
        if path_str[0] != path_str[-1]:
            raise ValueError(f"unmatched quotes: ({path_str[0]}) ({path_str[-1]})")
        path_str = path_str[1:-1]

    # platform detect
    try:
        p = WindowsPath(path_str)
    except NotImplementedError:  # non-windows system
        return PureWindowsPath(path_str), None
    return p, p.exists()

